# GraphQL with Keystone wants field type must be Output Type but got: undefined

Tags: express, graphql, keystonejs

I wan't to make GraphQL endpoint for my keystone.js app (via express middleware express-graphql).

Here is my Keystone Schema:

```
const keystone = require('keystone');

const Types = keystone.Field.Types;

const User = new keystone.List('User');

const localStorage = new keystone.Storage({
  adapter: keystone.Storage.Adapters.FS,
  fs: {
    path: './src/upload/avatars',
    publicPath: '/upload/avatars',
  },
});

User.add({
  name: { type: Types.Name, required: true, index: true },
  email: { type: Types.Email, initial: true, index: true },
  password: { type: Types.Password, initial: true, required: true },
}, 'Profile', {
  photo: { type: Types.File, storage: localStorage },
}, 'Permissions', {
  isAdmin: { type: Boolean, label: 'Can access Keystone', index: true },
},
);

// Provide access to Keystone
User.schema.virtual('canAccessKeystone').get(function () {
  return this.isAdmin;
});

User.defaultColumns = 'name, email, isAdmin';
User.register();
```

The key problem with field Photo which implemented as File type in keystone.js.

Below my GraphQL Schema:

```
import {   GraphQLSchema,   GraphQLID,   GraphQLList,   GraphQLNonNull,   GraphQLObjectType, } from 'graphql';

const keystoneTypes = require('keystone-graphql').Types; const keystone = require('keystone');

const User = keystone.list('User');

const userType = new GraphQLObjectType({   name: 'User',   fields: ()
=> ({
    id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
    name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(keystoneTypes.Name(User.fields.name)) },
    email: keystoneTypes.Email(User.fields.email),
    photo: keystoneTypes.File(User.fields.photo),   }), });

const queryRootType = new GraphQLObjectType({   name: 'Query',   fields: {
    users: {
      type: new GraphQLList(userType),
      resolve: () =>
        User.model.find().exec(),
    },
    user: {
      type: userType,
      args: {
        id: {
          description: 'id of the user',
          type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
        },
      },
      resolve: (_, args) => User.model.findById(args.id).exec(),
    },   }, });

export default new GraphQLSchema({   query: queryRootType, });
```

And the Field File implementation, which included in forked keystone-graphql package:

```
'use strict';

const GraphQL = require('graphql');

const KeystoneFileType = new GraphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'KeystoneFile',
    fields: {
    size: { type: GraphQL.GraphQLInt },
    mimetype: { type: GraphQL.GraphQLString },
    filename: { type: GraphQL.GraphQLString },
  },
});

module.exports = (field) => KeystoneFileType;
```

I want to make pull request to keystone-graphql package with File field when it will works properly. At this moment I have error from GraphQL:

```
Error: User.photo field type must be Output Type but got: undefined.
    at invariant (/Users/Vadim/Dropbox/WebStormProjects/mulibwanji/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/invariant.js:19:11)
    at /Users/Vadim/Dropbox/WebStormProjects/mulibwanji/node_modules/graphql/type/definition.js:335:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at defineFieldMap (/Users/Vadim/Dropbox/WebStormProjects/mulibwanji/node_modules/graphql/type/definition.js:326:14)
    at GraphQLObjectType.getFields (/Users/Vadim/Dropbox/WebStormProjects/mulibwanji/node_modules/graphql/type/definition.js:284:44)
    at typeMapReducer (/Users/Vadim/Dropbox/WebStormProjects/mulibwanji/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:206:25)
    at typeMapReducer (/Users/Vadim/Dropbox/WebStormProjects/mulibwanji/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:187:12)
    at /Users/Vadim/Dropbox/WebStormProjects/mulibwanji/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:216:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at typeMapReducer (/Users/Vadim/Dropbox/WebStormProjects/mulibwanji/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:207:27)
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at new GraphQLSchema (/Users/Vadim/Dropbox/WebStormProjects/mulibwanji/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:95:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Vadim/Dropbox/WebStormProjects/mulibwanji/graphql/Schema.js:58:16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment I bypassed with this:

```
export const File = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'KeystoneFileType',
  fields: {
    size: { type: GraphQLInt },
    filename: { type: GraphQLString },
    mimetype: { type: GraphQLString },
  },
});
```

So at this time it must to go without (field) => FileType, as I see, but I would be glad if somebody will find out the real issue.